# Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

```
> 2014-03-11 07:15:42,091 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Destroying
> connection that could not be successfully matched:
> org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener@7af45a93[state=DESTROYED
> mc=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@590c8c4e handles=0 lastUse=1394521919166 permit=false trackByTx=false
> mcp=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$OnePool@46cf828e
> context=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool@61845cf3
> xaResource=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$LocalXAResource@4066a7f5
> txSync=null] 
>
> 2014-03-11 07:15:42,161 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL
> Error: 0, SQLState: 22001 
>
> 2014-03-11 07:15:42,161 ERROR
> [JDBCExceptionReporter] Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: ''
> for column 'lastLoginTS' at row 1
```

Comment: so populate your datetime column correctly

Comment: Problem Solved!! i was using very old jdbc connector (mysql connector jar)